# Searching for the second word in a string

Tags: java

I'm a newbie in java and I was doing this exercise, to search the second word in a string, for example, if a string is "I love java" the program should return "love".

Here is my code:

```
import java.util.*;

// This program returns the second word of a string
public class SecondWord{
    public static void main(String[]args){
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("String: ");
        String x = in.nextLine();
        int pos = x.indexOf(" ");
        int pos1 = x.indexOf(" ", pos);
        String second = x.substring(pos, pos1);
        System.out.println(second);
    }
}
```

It compiles, but it returns nothing. What's wrong?

Comment: Because `pos == pos1`. You're missing a `+1`.

Comment: if you are free to choose, you can use `split()` instead

Comment: the easiest way would be to use split(" ") and then in retrieved array access what ever you with to with its index

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you are getting the next index of `" "` you should increase 1 in last index.

Change this

```
int pos1 = x.indexOf(" ", pos);
```

to

```
int pos1 = x.indexOf(" ", pos+1);
```

**Note**

You should increase the position by 1 when taking the substring to remove extra space in starting or `trim` it.

```
String second = x.substring(pos+1, pos1);
```

## Alternate Solution

One better way would be of doing same thing

```
String x = in.nextLine();
System.out.println(x.split(" ")[1]);
```

Split the string by `" "` and print the second element.

Comment: This solution crashes when you enter only 2 strings.

Answer (score 1):

I know this thread is pretty old, but I had run into the same question. Thank you for the solution using the split method, it was very helpful. However, I noticed a comment that said that the original code, with the pos + 1 fix, would not work if you entered only two words, and I also discovered that it would not work with only one word. This made me wonder if it was possible to find the second word using this approach without any errors when there were only one or two words. Here is what I came up with:

```
//For keyboard input
import java.util.Scanner;

// This program returns the second word of a string
public class SecondWord {
    public static void main(String[]args) {

        //Creates a scanner object for keyboard input
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        //Gets a string from the user
        System.out.print("String: ");
        String x = in.nextLine();

        //If the string contains more than one word
        if (x.contains(" ")) {
            //Finds the position of the first space, adds one to it to find the position of the first character of the second word
            int pos = x.indexOf(" ") + 1;

            //Replace the first space with a different character so the program can test if it has a second space
            char[] chars = x.toCharArray();
            chars[pos - 1] = 'a';
            x = String.valueOf(chars);

            //If there is a space after the second word
            if (x.contains(" ")) {

                //Finds the position of the space after the second word
                int pos1 = x.indexOf(" ", pos);

                //Gets the second word
                String second = x.substring(pos, pos1);

                //Displays the second word
                System.out.println(second);

                //If there is not a space after the second word
            } else {

                //Add a space to the end
                x += " ";

                //Finds the position of the space after the second word
                int pos1 = x.indexOf(" ", pos);

                //Gets the second word
                String second = x.substring(pos, pos1);

                //Displays the second word
                System.out.println(second);
            }
        } 
    }
}
```